# Need to login before going to "/"

Tags: angular, typescript, jhipster

i change my home.route.ts with this :

```
export const HOME_ROUTE: Route = {
  path: '',
  component: HomeComponent,
  data: {
    authorities: ['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN'],
    pageTitle: 'home.title'
  },
  canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
};
```

but, in terminal log, i see a tons of errors at every miliseconds like that :

```
2020-04-28 15:01:31.284 DEBUG 3588 --- [ XNIO-1 task-66] c.m.m.r.CustomAuditEventRepository       : Exit: add() with result = null
2020-04-28 15:01:31.285  WARN 3588 --- [ XNIO-1 task-66] o.z.problem.spring.common.AdviceTraits   : Unauthorized: Full authentication is required to access this resource
2020-04-28 15:01:31.286  WARN 3588 --- [ XNIO-1 task-66] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: Full authentication is required to access
 this resource]
```

What is the best way to do login before access to path '' ?

Sorry for my basic english, my first laguage is french.

Comment: Hi ! Specify the language that you are using when you ask a new question (specifiy it if it is node with typescript) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced something similar recently in a JHipster app in Angular.

It was due to few components included in page layout that require to know about the user: navbar, dev ribbon, ...

By default JHipster uses a modal for login form and this means that this popup is displayed in a page that includes the layout components I mentioned above.

My solution was to create a login screen with a simplified layout (e.g. no navbar) mapped on a `/login` route.